# How do I edit an existing buffer in a new tab in vim?

Tags: vim, tabs

Suppose I have started vim like this:

```
vim foo bar
```

Now I decide that I want each of those files in its own tab. Is there a way to do that without exiting vim and adding the `-p` option to my command line?

Comment: Many of you are probably looking for `tabe %` which is mentioned in  [liuyang1's answer](https://superuser.com/a/926567/442991) below.

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski Like I mentioned in [this comment to that answer](https://superuser.com/questions/66179/how-do-i-edit-an-existing-buffer-in-a-new-tab-in-vim#comment2176230_926567), `:tabe %` doesn't work with buffers that have no valid filepath. `:tab sb` works everytime.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You wish to open a buffer in a new tab ?

Split up the screen (Ctrl-W s), take up a window, and Ctrl-W T

Comment: Hmm. Not quite what I had in mind, but not bad for a start. I didn't know about `Ctrl-w T` yet. Of course, the first tab will still have two buffers that way.

Comment: No. After you split the screen into two windows, and open one of them in a new tab, it goes away from the first tab. It won't remain (at least it doesn't on my gvim72).
As far as buffers go, they are not connected to windows/tabs ... they are more like memory where vim stores file contents.

Comment: Ah! You're right. I was misinterpreting the output of `:ls`.

Comment: Also, ctrl-w V splits the window vertically.

Comment: CTRL-w v is the correct command for splitting windows vertically

Answer (score 45):

You can accomplish this by combining the [`tab`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#:tab) command with the [`sb[uffer]`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:sb) command.

First you'll need to know the buffer id of the buffer you wish to open in a new tab. You can find this out with the [`ls`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:ls) command:

```
:ls
  1 %a   "foo"                          line 1
  2      "bar"                          line 0
```

Once you have the id, you can easily open it in a new tab using:

```
:tab sb 2
```

The `sb` command normally opens the given buffer in a new split window, but the `tab` command causes it to open in a new tab, instead.

The `tab` command also allows you to specify where in the tab list the new tab should be created. For example, `:0tab sb 2` would result in the new ‘bar’ tab appearing at the beginning of the list instead of after the current tab.

Comment: You don’t need the buffer number, give it an unambiguous part of the buffer name and VIM does the rest for you.

Comment: This was so the answer I was looking for and needed. I was dismayed when `:tab buffer part-of-name` did not open a new tab! But `:tab sb part-of-name` worked like a charm. Thank you!!!!

Comment: This is not OP's exact question, but was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 36):

When you start vim like that, you don't get a vim client, the text editor is using the terminal or cmd prompt - the two files are in two different buffers.  Use `:ls` to list the buffers:

```
:ls
  1 %a   "foo"                 line 6
  2      "bar"             line 0
```

The %a is the active buffer.  You can use `:b2` to switch to buffer 2 or use `:bn` to cycle to the next or `:bp` for previous. I prefer (CTRL-W v) to split windows vertically, rather than (CTRL-W s), which splits horizontally.

If you have 2 files loaded & no tabs (yet), you can, `:tabnew` and in the new tab type `:b2`

If you want to always have buffers loaded into their own tabs, check out [this article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_every_buffer_in_its_own_tabpage).

Comment: Yes, but I want to have tabs.

Comment: So you already have started vim in a way that you have your files in the vim client, not in a cmd / terminal shell?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I use the shell to start vim like described above and then I have a running vim.

Comment: Ah! I guess I never really understood that buffers aren't local to tabs. I always thought (without thinking really much) that each tab has its own buffer list.

Comment: On my machine, `vim` will launch an editor within the shell.  To get the vim graphical user interface I have to use `gvim`.  And you are correct - buffers are global to the vim application.

Comment: Same here. vim will give me the "ungraphical" vim in my terminal window.

Comment: So in that case you'll need to switch between tabs. `gt` is the fastest, or you can tab switch the same way you switch between buffers - `:tabnext` (or `:tabn 2`),  `:tabprev`

Comment: oh man this gave me answer to all my questions. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 32):

A better way to accomplish what OP asked for is this:

`:bufdo tab split`

This will open each buffer into a tab of its own, no matter how many there are.  If you use this much, it's easy to make into a mapping in your .vimrc.  Combined with something like [this little vim plugin](http://pastebin.com/J9RwciFQ) the following will open every item from `:grep` (or [:Ack](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim)) in a tab of its own:

```
:grep foo
:QuickFixOpenAll
:bufdo tab split
```

Of course, when resorting to a plugin it would be easy enough to modify it to open the quickfix list contents in directly into tabs.

**UPDATE**: I've really got to give a shout-out to ggustafsson's comment below.  It's far and away the best answer of the lot and beautifully illustrates Vim's tendency towards compositional behavior.  The suggestion is:

```
 :tab sball
```

It's well worth looking up the Vim help for [:tab](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#:tab) and [:sball](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:sball) to see what's going on here.

Comment: An similar approach from a previous edit, for posterity, is `:bufdo execute "tabnew %"`.  I think the new approach is a bit clearer.

Comment: One caveat: if the starting buffer in vim isn't empty, this seems to open the last buffer twice.  I'll post an update if I find a simple fix.

Comment: `:tab sball` seems to work better.

Answer (score 8):

**1.** Open two files in Vim.

```
$ vim foo bar
```

**2.** Check the numbers of buffers.

```
:ls
  1%a "foo"
  2   "bar"
```

**3.** Chain two commands: `tabnew` to open a new tab and `b <buffer_number>` to load the desired buffer in the tab.

```
:tabnew | b 2
```

Comment: The problem with step 3 is that it first creates a new tab with an empty buffer, and then opens buffer 2, resulting in an extra untitled buffer in the buffer list. Better to use `:tab sb 2`

Comment: @rkjnsn you should post that as an answer - it best answers the question 'how do I edit an existing buffer in a new tab in vim?'

Comment: @JonnyLeeds done.

Answer (score 4):

Just add some point which other guys didn't mention.

- current window to new tab

If have multiple window, `<C-W>T` will move this window to new tab. However, this shortcut only for "Window", not "buffer". If prefer this style, `:sp` or `<C-W>s` to duplicate current buffer to one more window, then `<C-W>T` to move it to new tab.

4 keystrokes or 7 keystrokes.

- current buffer to new tab

`:tabe %` to open new tab for current buffer.

7 keystrokes.

- buffer to new tab

If use CtrlP plugin, also could use "CtrlPBuffer", then with `<C-t>` shortcut to open it with new tab page.
This style, easily to switch to different buffers.

With shortcut of "CtrlPBuffer", 4 keystrokes or more.

Comment: `:tabe %` is what I've been looking for for a long time, thanks!

Comment: No, `:tabe %` doesn't really open a new tab for current buffer. What happens is that `%` gets expanded to the filepath of the current buffer and `:tabe` opens that path. Vim will see you're trying to open a file you already have open and will reuse the buffer you have. This means that this doesn't work with buffers that have no filepath. If you open up a new file with `:new` and you haven't saved it, you can't put it on a new tab with this. The real command you need is what rkjnsn put in their answer: `:tab sb %` or shorter: `:tab sb`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) plugin. You could list the buffers using `:Buffers`, then select the specific buffer with `<C-j/k>` (or filter by typing buffer number or file name), then use `<C-t>` to open the selected buffer in new tab.

I use below mapping to quickly list the buffers:

```
nnoremap <leader>b :Buffers<CR>
```

Comment: The best way ever !