# How do I switch buffer with gVim?

Tags: gvim

If I create multiple buffers on gVim (gnome interface for vim), how do I switch buffer ?
Vim doc says it's `F8`  key but it doesn't work...

Any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [how-do-i-edit-an-existing-buffer-in-a-new-tab-in-vim](http://superuser.com/questions/66179/how-do-i-edit-an-existing-buffer-in-a-new-tab-in-vim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switching buffers is done *in general* with `:bp[revious]` and `:bn[ext]` (the part in the brackets being optional). If you don't feel like typing that every time, you can map it to some key, or key combination.

```
nnoremap <F1> :bp<cr>
nnoremap <F2> :bn<cr>
```

(feel free to modify to your needs)

If you're thinking about *switching* between splits, that is done with `<C-W> some key`, depending on where you want to go. They're all really nicely described in `help CTRL-W`, but the most commonly used are `V` and `S` for splitting, and then `C-W C-W` (twice) for switching between open splits.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you create those multiple buffers. If they are in multiple windows, then you can switch between windows with `Ctrl-W Ctrl-W` and related commands. See

```
:help window-move-cursor
```

If the bvffers are in multiple tabs, you can switch between tabs with `gt` and related commands. See

```
:help gt
```

Using `:helpgrep f8` and `:helpgrep F8`, I don't find any mention in the Vim docs of F8 being used to switch buffers. What Vim docs are you referring to?

Comment: I create buffers using `:split:` or `:vsplit:`. I have found it on a Vim wiki in fact...

Comment: In that case you have created new windows, so you can use `Ctrl-W Ctrl-W` to jump to the next window, or `Ctrl-W k` to jump to the window above the current one, for example. There is no default mapping for F8, but you could make your own. Perhaps the wiki mentions such a mapping.